# How to delete multiple Nuget package files in Build.xml

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, nuget

I wrote a Build.xml file to create a Nuget package for a module on my solution and then upload it to a MyGet repository. After that, I want to remove the nupkg file generated, in order to keep the pack only in the repository. The first step is working fine but not the removing part. I'm trying this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Target Name="Package">
<!-- Package the project -->
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(BuildDir)" Command="NuGet.exe pack &quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)&quot;\Service.nuspec -Version &quot;$(BUILD_NUMBER)&quot;" />
<!-- Upload the Nuget package -->
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(BuildDir)" Command="NuGet.exe push *.nupkg {auth-code} -source https://www.myget.org/{myget-source}" />
<!--Removing the Nuget package files created. -->
<Delete Files="*.nupkg" />
</Target>
</Project>
```

Notice that "auth-code" and "myget-source" corresponds to the actual values that were substituted for obvious reasons. The question is how to achieve remove all of the Nuget packages (*.nupkg) files after pushing them to the repository. I tried passing to the DeleteFiles function the complete name of a file and it works. So, I don't know why it doesn't when I specify the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete using wildcards, but you can delete a list of files. Like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <OldNuGetPackages Include="$(BuildDir)*.nupkg"/>
</ItemGroup>
<Delete Files="@(OldNuGetPackages)"/>
```

Comment: It worked great! Just what i was looking for. Thanks